# How to loop through a pandas dataframe to query with another dataframe? or merge using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I got 2 dataframes:

this is a table that shows the user info, without the role name:

| Name | Role ID | Number of Roles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Daniel | 45678 | 1 |
| James | 45678 | 1 |
| Jacob | 45678,12345,98765 | 3 |
| Erin | 98765,45678 | 2 |
| Ash | 12345 | 1 |
| Bob | 12345 | 1 |

this table shows all of the existing Roles:

| Role ID | Role Name |
| --- | --- |
| 45678 | Admin |
| 12345 | Supervisor |
| 98765 | Manager |

using python pandas, I'm trying to find a way to merge these table into one so it will show the info like that:

| Name | Role ID | Number of Roles | Role Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Daniel | 45678 | 1 | Admin |
| James | 45678 | 1 | Admin |
| Jacob | 45678,12345,98765 | 3 | Admin, Supervisor, Manager |
| Erin | 98765,45678 | 2 | Manager, Admin |
| Ash | 12345 | 1 | Admin |
| Bob | 12345 | 1 | Admin |

I'm new to python, sorry if this is simple, could find the solution anywhere else. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your expected output is not right.

You can use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and df2 and regex from df2's `Role Name` to get what you need:

```
d = df2.set_index('Role ID')['Role Name']
reg = '|'.join(df2['Role ID'].unique().astype(str))
df1['Role Name'] = df1['Role ID'].str.replace(f'({reg})', 
                              lambda m: d[int(m.group(1))], regex=True)

print(df1)

     Name             Role ID  Number of Roles                  Role Name
0  Daniel               45678                 1                     Admin 
1   James               45678                 1                     Admin 
2   Jacob   45678,12345,98765                 3  Admin,Supervisor,Manager 
3    Erin         98765,45678                 2             Manager,Admin 
4     Ash               12345                 1                Supervisor 
5     Bob               12345                 1                Supervisor
```